# D3.js stack layout transition and alignment | with fiddle (reworked)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, html5-canvas, data-visualization

After multiple hours of trial and error I think I may miss something general.
I managed to get a horizontal stacked bar chart working (static) in d3.js.

Now I am facing two problems:

1. How could the bars be aligned in one vertical line?
2. How could dataset 1 be changed (transitioned) to dataset 2?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DTBQs/4/)

I don't expect a complete code rework, but the tutorials out there don't help me.
I think this could probably be a good reference, since there are many questions about stack layout on stack overflow right now, showing that people are seeking for further explanation of this technique. Other transition examples for stack layouts are (at the moment) unnecessarily complex.

1. I think the reason why the bar is not aligned to the left could be in:

   - the scale function:

     ```
     .domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
     ```
   - the `x` attribute:

     ```
     x:function(d){      return +x(d.y)+x(d.y0)}
     ```
   - the `width` attribute:

     ```
     width:function(d){  return x(d.y)},
     ```

   Does anyone have an idea about how to make all the stacked bar charts begin at one place?
2. I know normal update/exit/enter mechanisms but here i don't have an idea about how to (code) efficiently transition this stack layout. Where could I store the update sections of the inner `rect` elements or how to access the `rects` within the `g` selection which surrounds them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<body>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width",200)
.attr("height", 200);

var testArrayForStack = [
    [{x:0,y:20,id:'a'},{x:1,y:30,id:'a'},{x:2,y:40,id:'a'}],
    [{x:0,y:20,id:'b'},{x:1,y:30,id:'b'},{x:2,y:40,id:'b'}],
    [{x:0,y:20,id:'c'},{x:1,y:30,id:'c'},{x:2,y:40,id:'c'}]
]

var testArrayForStack_2 = [
    [{x:0,y:30,id:'a'},{x:1,y:20,id:'a'},{x:2,y:20,id:'a'}],
    [{x:0,y:40,id:'b'},{x:1,y:10,id:'b'},{x:2,y:10,id:'b'}],
    [{x:0,y:50,id:'c'},{x:1,y:45,id:'c'},{x:2,y:50,id:'c'}]
]

//test array 1
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
var stacked = stack(testArrayForStack);
//test array 2
var stack2 = d3.layout.stack()
var stacked = stack(testArrayForStack);
//log stacked array
console.log('its stacked : ',stacked)
//scale
x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, 100])
.domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
//color
var col = d3.scale.category10();
//update for parents
var stack_up = svg.selectAll('g')
.data(stacked);
//enter for stack parents and there is a nesting for children rect elements   
//how works a transition here (to dataset 2)? How to align them to a left line?
var stack_ent = stack_up
.enter()
.append('g')
.selectAll('rect')
.data(function(d){return d})
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr({
    y:function(d){      return (d.x*30 )},
    x:function(d){      return +x(d.y)+x(d.y0)},
    height:10,
    width:function(d){  return x(d.y)},
    fill:function(d){   return col(d.id)}
});
</body>
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: what's the difference between this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097632/d3-js-stack-layout-transition-and-alignment-with-fiddle ?

Comment: I wrote this reworked question because the other one was not sufficiently designed. Because I could not find any delete button on the web page and the old question didn't have any code highlighting (for example) I edited the old question subsequently.If you want to see the difference at first glance I could make it look more worse, I just thought that it's better to change in case someone sees it. Additionally the old question got a down vote without any comment about -why- so probably no one will klick it.The down voter also didn't remove the down vote even though its now different.That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLhQK/7/). The x attribute of the bars is changed to

```
    x: function (d) {
        return x(d.y0);
    }
```

Drawing bars is a separate function. It is called on update button click with a new data.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved all my questions. I would press the up button two times if I could ^^.